# SQLAlchemy recursive CTE query doesn't return non-column members?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression

I have the following class:

```
class Catalog(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'catalog'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    parentid = Column(String, ForeignKey('catalog.id'))
    name = Column(String)
    parent = relationship("Catalog", remote_side=[id])]

    @property
    def operative_name_stamp(self):
        node = self
        while not node.name and node.parent:
            node = node.parent
        return node.name
```

If I do some recursive CTE-based query:

```
hierarchy = session.query(
        Catalog, literal(0).label('level'))\
        .filter(Catalog.parentid == null())\
        .cte(name="hierarchy", recursive=True)

parent = aliased(hierarchy, name="p")
children = aliased(Catalog, name="c")
hierarchy = hierarchy.union_all(
            session.query(
                children,
                (parent.c.level + 1).label("level"))
            .filter(children.parentid == parent.c.id))

result = session.query(Catalog, hierarchy.c.level)\
        .select_entity_from(hierarchy).all()
```

This will only give me a hierachy of tuples with column members, but the non-column member --`operative_name_stamp` -- is missing.

Is there a way to include those members in the result?

Comment: I don't understand for CTE, my input is an entity class, but my output becomes a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be easily solved by using a dictionary instead of list as returned result. That way you can literally "look up" whatever you like by primary keys. This reminds me of how seemingly complicated life can be!